# How to store json-patch operations in redis queue and guarantee their consistency?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, redis, json-patch

I have collaborative web application that handles JSON-objects like the following:

```
var post = {
  id: 123,
  title: 'Sterling Archer',    
  comments: [
    {text: 'Comment text', tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']},
    {text: 'Comment test', tags: ['tag2', 'tag5']}
  ]  
};
```

My approach is using [rfc6902 (JSONPatch) specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) with [jsonpatch](https://github.com/Starcounter-Jack/JSON-Patch#user-content-usage) library for patching JSON document. All such documents store in MongoDB database and as you know the last one very slow for frequent writes.

To get more speed and highload application I use redis as queue for a patch operations like the following:

```
{ "op": "add", "path": "/comments/2", "value":  {text: 'Comment test3', tags: ['tag4']}" }
```

I just store all such patch operations in queue and at midnight run cron script to get all patches and construct full document and update it in MongoDB database.

I don't understand yet what should I do in case corrupted patch like:

```
{ "op": "add", "path": "/comments/0/tags/5", "value": 'tag4'}
```

The patch above don't gets applied to document above because `tags` array has length only 3 (according official docs https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#page-5)

```
 The specified index MUST NOT be greater than the number of elements in the array.
```

So when user is online he don't get any errors because his patch operations get stored in redis queue but next day he get broken document due broken patch that don't got applied in cron script.

So my question if how could I guarantee that all patches that stored in redis queue is correct and don't corrupts primary document?

Comment: at a high level what would you prefer to happen in the event of a corrupted diff? would you want to attempt to correct the issue, or just throw out the diff?

Comment: How does the user produce a bad patch?

Comment: I dont know. I need to somehow prevent corrupted diff. Maybe there is best practices?

Comment: How does google docs resolve this issue?

Comment: How corrupted patch is getting created? That needs to be identified first. Can it be the case that the JSON patch node pushed into from the program itself is not proper? Please share the code pushing JSON data and cron.

Comment: @Vickrant 
> How corrupted patch is getting created?
For example use send corrupted patch via Chrome Developers Tools or I will have error in my code.

Comment: > Can it be the case that the JSON patch node pushed into from the program itself is not proper? Yes, in theory I can a bug in my code

Comment: > Please share the code pushing JSON data and cron: 
I use https://github.com/Starcounter-Jack/JSON-Patch module. You can see a lot of examples, so in my cron I use the same one

Answer (score 3):

As with any system that can become inconsistent, you must allow for patches to be applied as quickly as possible if you wish to catch conflicts sooner and decrease the likelihood of running into them. That is likely your *main* issue if you are not notifying the other clients of any updated data as soon as possible (and are just waiting for the CRON to run to update the shared data that the other clients can access).

As others have asked, it's important to understand how a "bad" patch got into the operation queue in the first place. Here are some guesses from my standpoint:

1. A user had applied some operations that got lost in translation. How? I don't know, but it would explain the discrepancy.
2. Operations are not being applied in the correct order. How? I don't know. I have no code to go off of.

Although I have no code to go off of, I can take a shot in the dark and help you analyze the latter point. The first thing we need to analyze is the different scenarios that may come up with updating a "shared" resource. It's important to note that, in any system that must eventually be consistent, we care about the:

1. Order of the operations.
2. How we will deal with conflicts.

The latter is really up to you, and you will need a good notification/messaging system to update the "truth" that clients see.

## Scenario 1

User A applies operations 1 & 2. The document is updated on the server and then User B is notified of this. User B was going to apply operations 3 & 4, but these operations (in this order) do not conflict with operations 1 & 2. All is well in the world. This is a good situation.

## Scenario 2

User A applies operations 1 & 2. User B applies operations 3 & 4.

If you apply the operations atomically per user, you can get the following queues:

[1,2,3,4]   [3,4,1,2]

Anywhere along the line, if there is a conflict, you must notify either User A or User B based on "who got there first" (or any other weighting semantics you wish to use). Again, how you deal with conflicts is up to you. If you have not read up on vector clocks, you should do so.

If you don't apply operations atomically per user, you can get the following queues:

[1,2,3,4]  [3,4,1,2]  [1,3,2,4]  [3,1,4,2]  [3,1,2,4]  [1,3,4,2]

As you can see, forgoing atomic updates per user increases the combinations of updates and will therefore *increase* the likelihood of a collision happening. I urge you to ensure that operations are being added to the queue atomically per user.

## A Recap

Some important things you should remember:

1. Make sure updates to the queue are atomically applied per user.
2. Figure out how you will deal with several versions of a shared resource arising from multiple mutations from different clients (again I suggest you read up on vector clocks).
3. Don't update a shared resource that may be accessed by several clients in real-time as a cron job.
4. When there is a conflict that cannot be resolved, figure out how you will deal with it.
5. As a result of point 3, you will need to come up with a notification system so that clients can get updated resources quickly. As a result of point 4, you may choose to include telling clients that something went wrong with their update. Something that has just come to the top of my head is that you're already using Redis, which has pub/sub capabilities.

**EDIT**:

It seems like Google Docs handles conflict resolutions with transformations. That is, by shifting whole characters/lines over to make way for a hybrid application of all operations: https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/09/whats-different-about-new-google-docs_22.html

As I had said before, it's all up to how you want to handle your own conflicts, which should largely be determined by the application/product itself and its use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At now I use revision number and increase on each patch. So if user send wrong rev num I drop his patch. I do understand your suggest and want to try Redis. what do you think about the following scenario: I store my JSON document in MongoDB (for example) and when needed save into the Redis (until users online) and after users offline I flush all Redis's data into MongoDB back

Comment: I tend to agree with @DhruvPathak's answer. Although I've given you a synopsis on how you may be running into your issues, I think you should start simple and do something like Celery + Redis + Mongo.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you are introducing unneeded complexity instead of simpler solution. These would be my alternate suggestions instead of your approach of a json patch cron which is very hard to make consistent and atomic.

1. **Use mongodb only** : With proper database design and indexing, and proper hdarware allocation/sharding, the write performance of mongodb is really fast. And the kind of operations you are using in jsonpatch are natively supported in mongodb BSON documents and their query language .e.g $push,$set,$inc,$pull etc. 
   Perhaps you want to not interrupt users activities with a syncronous write to Mongodb , for that the solution is using async queus as mentioned in point#2.

   2.**Use task queues & mongodb**: Instead of storing patches in redis like you do now, you can push the patching task to a task queue, which will asyncronously do the mongodb update , and user will not experience any slow performance. One very good task queue is [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) , which can use Redis as a broker & messaging backend. So, each users updates get a single task, and will get applied to mongodb by the task queue, and there will be no performance hit.

Comment: Although I've given you ways to analyze the situation and potentially tackle consistency problems, I agree with this answer.

Comment: @DhruvPathak I like your suggestions but don't understand how could I update my document via `$push`,`$set`,`$inc`, `$pull` etc. Let's say how could I update the `post` document with patch `{ "op": "add", "path": "/comments/2", "value":  {text: 'Comment test3', tags: ['tag4']}` by using MongoDB operators. Please can you provide a short example?

Comment: @Erik That would be `db.myCollection.update({_id:123},{'$push':{'comments':{text: 'Comment test3', tags: ['tag4']}})`

Comment: @DhruvPathak thanks for the answer. I've tried your suggestion for all my patch operation and found that I can't make `move` patch operation http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902#appendix-A.7 because MongoDB doesn't have one. Is it possible somehow to workaround this?

Comment: You can achieve the same using http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/position/ , but it will need 2 commands in sequence. Or execute javascript command which executes both these commands on server side.